# Haskell error "No instance for (Eq a0) arising from a use of..."

Tags: haskell

Anyone knows why the following code fails in "`matchListWith eq [] []`"?

-- failure.hs

```
matchListWith :: (Eq a) => (a -> a -> Bool) -> [a] -> [a] -> Bool
matchListWith f (x:xs) (y:ys) = (f x y) && (matchListWith f xs ys)
matchListWith _ []     []     = True
matchListWith _ _      _      = False

eq :: (Eq a) => a -> a -> Bool
eq a b = (a == b)

main = do
   print (matchListWith eq [1, 3] [1, 3])
   print (matchListWith eq [1, 3] [1])
   print (matchListWith eq [1] [1, 3])
   print (matchListWith eq [3, 1] [1, 3])
   print (matchListWith eq [1] [])
   print (matchListWith eq [] [])
```

-- eof

The error is:

```
failure.hs:16:11:
    No instance for (Eq a0) arising from a use of `matchListWith'
    The type variable `a0' is ambiguous
    Possible fix: add a type signature that fixes these type variable(s)
    Note: there are several potential instances:
      instance Eq a => Eq (GHC.Real.Ratio a) -- Defined in `GHC.Real'
      instance Eq () -- Defined in `GHC.Classes'
      instance (Eq a, Eq b) => Eq (a, b) -- Defined in `GHC.Classes'
      ...plus 22 others
    In the first argument of `print', namely `(matchListWith eq [] [])'
    In a stmt of a 'do' block: print (matchListWith eq [] [])
    In the expression:
      do { print (matchListWith eq [1, 3] [1, 3]);
           print (matchListWith eq [1, 3] [1]);
           print (matchListWith eq [1] [1, 3]);
           print (matchListWith eq [3, 1] [1, 3]);
           .... }
```

The weird things is, if I load the two functions in GHCi, `matchListWith eq [] []`,
works just fine.

```
*Main> matchListWith eq [] []
True
*Main>
```

I'm using GHC version 7.6.3.

Comment: You know you could just write `(==)` instead of `eq`, right?

Answer (score 3):

The reason is because when you call

```
matchListWith eq [] []
```

The compiler doesn't know what type of list it is.  All it knows is that it's a value of type `[a]`, but that does not put the `Eq a =>` constraint on it.  Change it to

```
matchListWith eq [] ([] :: [Int])
```

and it should compile

---

Sometimes you have to give GHC a bit of help to know what types it's working with.  It would be the same if you tried

```
myFunc :: m Int
myFunc = do
    let x = 1
        y = 2
    return $ x + y
```

This wouldn't compile because the compiler isn't told that `m` is a `Monad`, you have to add the extra context of

```
myFunc :: Monad m => m Int
```

for it to work.

The reason why it works in GHCi is because there's a bit more eager type inference.  GHCi will often pick a more concrete type than GHC will in order to make the interactive part easier to use.

Comment: Now that you know the fix, I'd remove the `Eq a =>` from `matchListWith`'s type declaration. It's not needed at all!

Comment: @Guido That is a good point, the matchListWith function has no need for any type constraints.  It's also functionally equivalent to `and $ zipWith f xs ys`

Comment: In this case, it’s sound to default `Eq` to anything. There are plenty of cases where it isn’t, though (e.g., `show . read`). Anyone happen to know if that’s possible to determine in general?